# $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2x^2y}$ , $1\le x<\infty $ , $\frac{1}{x}\le y<x$ marginal of X and Y is?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

$f(x,y)=\dfrac{1}{2x^2y}$ , $1\le x<\infty $  , $\dfrac{1}{x}\le y<x$

Derive marginal probability density function of $X$ and $Y$

I have a problem in calculating marginal of Y.

We have to calculate $\int_{x}f(x,y)dx$

Usually, I draw graphs to get my limits of integration first before calculating marginal distribution but this time I am unable to figure out limits.

Graph is [image]

Function changes.

I have $y<x$ and $y<1/x$ as well . So how do I calculate marginal in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}f_X(x)&=\int_{y}f(x,y)dy=\int_{1/x}^x\frac{1}{2x^2y}dy=\frac{1}{2x^2}\int_{1/x}^x\left(\ln{y}\right)'dy=\frac{\ln{x}}{x^2}\cdot\mathbf1_{\{x\ge1\}}\end{align*}
For $f_Y$ you need to take cases depending on whether $y<1$ or $y\ge 1$. This is best determined from your graph:

- $y<1$: Then $1/x<y<x$ implies that $x>1/y>1/x$. You also have that $x\ge 1$, but since, $1/y\ge 1$  $$f_Y(y)=\int_{1/y}^{\infty}f(x,y)dx$$
- $y\ge1$: Then $1\le y<x$ implies that 
  $$f_Y(y)=\int_{y}^{\infty}f(x,y)dx$$

Comment: Thanks I got it.

Comment: Can I ask some stats inference doubts to you ?

Comment: @Damn1o1 Yeah, sure, if they concern this question (and are really short to answer) then do it as a comment here. Otherwise, post a new question and just notify me so that I do not miss it.

Comment: I just looked at your picture and I think you are a professor (guessed by looking at the classroom behind you). I just wanted to contact you for quick doubts. And how may I notify you if I want to discuss something with you?

Comment: I am just a tutor, but thanks. Just write a note here that you posted a question so that I do not miss it.

Comment: You must have question banks with you like exercises or somthing. Can you provide my any set of questions based on UMVUE,Cramer Rao lower bound, estimation or hypothesis? Actually, I have an exam next year Feb. And I want to practice some inference questions. Can you help?

Comment: No, I am sorry. Unfortunately not. I should also have used the past tense: I was a tutor. But also when I was, I had only probability exercises not so much in statistics. Nevertheless, thanks for asking!

Comment: Ohh. So I will text you here when I post any porbability question.

Answer (score 4):

Guide:

- Once you fix $x$, $y$ takes value from $\frac1{x}$ to $x$, those are your lower and upper limit.
- Just compute $\int_{\frac1x}^x \frac1{2x^2y}\, dy$

Edit:

Depends on whether your $y$ is above or below $1$.

- If $y$ is below $1$, the lower limit is $\frac1y$.
- If $y$ is at least $1$, the lower limit is $x$.
- The upper limit is $\infty$.

Comment: Oh yess thanks !

Answer (score 4):

$\frac 1 {2x^{2}} \int_{1/x} ^{x} \frac 1 y dy=\frac 1 {2x^{2}}  (log \, x -\log \, (1/x))=\frac {log \, x} {x^{2}}$ for $1 <x <\infty$. The marginal of $Y$ is $\int_{\max \{y,\frac 1 y\}}^{\infty} \frac 1 {2x^{2}y} dx=\frac 1 {2\max \{1, y^{2}\}}$.